# How To Read a CSV File Using Pandas

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am having trouble running my code. I want to load the "Forest Fires" dataset by calling the `pandas` method `read_csv()` with the name of the csv file `"forestfires.csv"` (docs) and store the result in a variable `forestfire_df`.

The interpreter keeps throwing this error

```
name 'forestfire_df' is not defined".
```

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


if not os.path.exists("forestfires.csv"):
    raise Exception(f"The forestfires.csv is not detected in your local path! " \
                    f"You need to move the 'forestfires.csv' file to the same " \
                    f"location/directory as this notebook which is {os.getcwd()}")     
# TODO 1.1

display(forestfire_df)

display(pd.read_csv("forestfires.csv"))

([
    (np.all(forestfire_df.iloc[0].values == np.array([7, 5, 'mar', 'fri', 86.2, 26.2, 94.3, 5.1, 8.2, 51, 6.7, 0.0, 0.0],
      dtype=object)), '')
])
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What were you expecting `display(forestfire_df)` to do??? You hadn't even read the CSV file at that point, and even at the point where you *do* read it, you don't assign it to a variable, so you can make no further use of the data.

Answer (score 0):

`forestfire_df` will have to be defined before it is displayed, for example with a line like:

```
forestfire_df = pd.read_csv("forestfires.csv")
```